# JQuery animation loop on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, animation, hover

this is probably a very basic question, but I am trying to animate an image (with a kind of pulse effect) when a button is hovered over.

So far I have this:

```js
$("#austriaBtn").mouseenter(
 function animate(){
  $('#austria').animate({width:"35", top:"-=4", left:"-=4"},600);
  $('#austria').animate({width:"27", top:"+=4", left:"+=4"},600, animate);
  }
 );
```

Now, I can hover over the button (austriaBtn) and the image (austria) starts to pulsate, however, when I take the mouse off, it carries on pulsating. How can I stop it?
I know it must be something to do with stop(), but whenever I try to put it in, the animation stops working all together.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Put [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) in a [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) function.

```
$("#austriaBtn").mouseleave(function(){ $('#austria').stop(true,true); });
```

The `true` arguments in `.stop()` are as follows:

- clear animation queue (default is `false`; shouldn't be an issue.)
- jump to end of animation (default is `false`; stops the element from being caught in the middle of an animation. important here.)

Comment: @Exinferis 

So I have tried adding the `.stop()` inside a `.mouseleave()` as above. However, it is resulting in some very strange and erratic behaviour.

When I take the mouse off of the button, the image starts to drift slowly in a diagonal direction, which makes me think that it's not being stopped completely and that the `top:"+=4", left:"+=4"` are still being executed.

Comment: Just tried knocking up a jsfiddle but it worked in that o_O 
Will try to show it in some other way, but it might take a while. Thanks for your help so far, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Exinferis Okay, I just tried making another JS fiddle... and yes, it's showing the strange behaviour. i.e. when you mouse on/off quickly, it gets stuck, starts drifting etc.
http://jsfiddle.net/v88j9dx7/

Comment: I still can't seem to figure this one out.  I think it's getting stuck in an infinite loop sometimes, or not resetting the values. Any idea why it's doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the corresponding mouseleave event, thus catching the event when the mouse leaves the button and then stop the animation.

```
$("#austriaBtn").mouseleave(
  function() {
    $("#austria").stop();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a lock variable:

```
var stopAnimation = false;
$("#austriaBtn").mouseenter(
    function animate(){
        if(stopAnimation){
            stopAnimation = false;
        } else {
            $('#austria').animate({width:"35", top:"-=4", left:"-=4"},600);
            $('#austria').animate({width:"27", top:"+=4", left:"+=4"},600, animate);
        }
    }
);
$("#austriaBtn").mouseleave(
    function(){
        $('#austria').stop();
        stopAnimation = true;
    }
);
```